# How to save plot in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I am using StatsPlots package to perform basic plotting.

```
df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B =rand(10))
@df df plot(:A, :B)
```

it returns a plot file like below as I expected. [image]

Is there anyway I can save this plot image into my machine(Ubuntu) as a file?

Comment: Perhaps different backend, but there is file saving: https://www.tutorialkart.com/julia/save-plot-png-jpeg-julia/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
using StatsPlots, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B =rand(10))
plotd = @df df StatsPlots.plot(:A, :B);
savefig(plotd,"file.png")
```

Also note that other extension are available. The `savefig` documentation reads:

> "All backends support png and pdf file types, some also support svg, ps, eps, html and tex."